# Flutter FutureBuilder with lazy loading

Tags: android, flutter, lazy-loading, flutter-futurebuilder

Good Afternoon. I'm new in flutter, I want to ask if it is possible to implement lazy loading for data retrieved from API which is rendered using FutureBuilder. and this is my code. sorry for the api URL I filled dummy. Thank you the first for iteration is page 1 (content 1-10). second for iteration are nested. The first for represents the page, and the next represents the 10 content on that page.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:statistik_malang/constants.dart';
import 'package:statistik_malang/details_screen.dart';
import 'package:statistik_malang/model_publikasi.dart';
import 'package:statistik_malang/product.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


void main() {
  runApp(publikasi_secondpage());
}

class publikasi_secondpage extends StatefulWidget {
  // const publikasi_secondpage({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _publikasi_secondpageState createState() => _publikasi_secondpageState();
}

class _publikasi_secondpageState extends State<publikasi_secondpage> {
  

  Future<List<Publikasimod>> getPublicationAll() async {
    String apiURL =
        "link of api";

    var apiResult = await http.get(Uri.parse(apiURL));
    var jsonObject = json.decode(apiResult.body);
    List<dynamic> listpublikasi = (jsonObject as Map<String, dynamic>)["data"];
    
// content in page 1 (1 to 10)    
List<Publikasimod> publikasimods = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < listpublikasi[1].length; i++) {
      publikasimods.add(Publikasimod.createPublikasimod(listpublikasi[1][i]));
    }

    
// content in page i (11-20, 21-30, ...) 
    for (int i = 2; i < listpublikasi[0]["pages"] + 1; i++) {
      String apiURL2 =
          "link of api";

      var apiResult2 = await http.get(Uri.parse(apiURL2));
      var jsonObject2 = json.decode(apiResult2.body);
      List<dynamic> listberita2 = (jsonObject2 as Map<String, dynamic>)["data"];

      for (int j = 0; j < listberita2[1].length; j++) {
        
        publikasimods.add(Publikasimod.createPublikasimod(listberita2[1][j]));
      }
    }
   
    return publikasimods;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Daftar Publikasi Terbaru"),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: getPublicationAll(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.error != null) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Text("tidak ada koneksi, mohon periksa koneksi internet anda")
                ],
              );
            } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return Column(
                children: [Text("data null")],
              );
            } else {
              return Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: kDefaultPaddin, vertical: 20),
                    child: GridView.builder(
                      
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          mainAxisSpacing: kDefaultPaddin,
                          crossAxisSpacing: kDefaultPaddin,
                          childAspectRatio: 0.55),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => itemBuku(
                          id: 1,
                          // title: null,
                          title: snapshot.data[index].title,
                          cover: snapshot.data[index].cover,
                          date: snapshot.data[index].rl_date,
                          press: () => Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => DetailsScreen(
                                          product: snapshot.data[index],
                                        )),
                              )),
                    ),
                  ))
                ],
              );
            }
          },
        ));
  }
}

class itemBuku extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String date;
  final String cover;
  final Function press;
  final int id;
  const itemBuku({
    Key key,
    this.title,
    this.date,
    this.id,
    this.cover,
    this.press,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: press,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultPaddin),
              height: 230,
              width: 169,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                // color: product.color,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                image: DecorationImage(
                    // fit: BoxFit.fill, image: NetworkImage(cover)),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    image: NetworkImage(cover)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: kDefaultPaddin / 4),
            child: Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          Text(date,
              // style: TextStyle(),
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the [easy list view](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_listview) package. That will help you with lazy loader
or if you want it by your self then follow this [this blog](https://www.initpals.com/flutter/how-to-lazy-load-large-list-from-http-rest-api-with-pagination-in-flutter/) or [geeksforgeeks blog](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-lazy-loader/#:%7E:text=The%20Lazy%20loader%20is%20a,endless%20content%20in%20a%20ListView.&text=For%20the%20sake%20of%20simplicity,the%20content%20in%20the%20app.)